# What breaks if I use a $G$-module instead of a $\mathbb{K}[G]$-module: Induced reps, Frobenius reciprocity?

Tags: permutations, modules, representation-theory, group-homomorphism, group-rings

## The Question

I use $\mathbb{K}G$-module to denote a $G$-action on a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ (side question - is this the standard notation?).

A $\mathbb{K}[G]$-module differs in that we allow formal sums of elements of $G$ in forming the group algebra $\mathbb{K}[G]$, making sure that everything is compatible with the abelian group structures.

Suppose I work with just $\mathbb{K}G$-modules - **do the standard constructions of induced modules and Frobenius reciprocity still hold**?

My guess is yes, because really forming an induced module in the $R$-module setting ($R$ a ring) just seems to mainly depend on defining the rule for how elements of $R$ are compatible with "multiplication" and the tensor product (the rest is just ensuring linearity), similarly for forming the Hom$(V,W)$ objects to prove Frobenius reciprocity. So in the $\mathbb{K}G$-module case, we just don't have to prove the axioms that involve compatibility with a second binary operation on $G$, because there's no sum on $G$. But also I'm very new to this, so am worried I'm missing something.

## Background for why I'd ask this

Suppose I form the span over $\mathbb{C}$ of elements of $S_n$ of a specific cycle type:

\begin{align}
V_{\lambda} = \text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}\{\sigma \in S_n \,\,|\,\, 
\text{$\sigma$ has cycle type $\lambda$} \}
\end{align}

Because conjugating by elements of $S_n$ preserves cycle type, I can define a $S_n$-action on $V_\lambda$ as

\begin{align}
g \cdot \sigma = g \sigma g^{-1}, \quad g \in S_n, \, \sigma \in V_{\lambda}
\end{align}

However, it doesn't seem like I can use conjugation to make this space into a  module over the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$, because $g^{-1}$ doesn't exist in general for $g \in \mathbb{C}[S_n]$. That is the following axiom can't be shown to hold:

\begin{align}
(g_1 + g_2)\cdot x \stackrel{?}{=} g_1 \cdot x + g_2 \cdot x
\end{align}

I need to perform calculations using induced modules and Frobenius reciprocity with objects like $V_{\lambda}$ and the action by conjugation, but only see these topics discussed in the literature using the full group algebra.

I know it's technically not my stated question, but any comment on how to get around this difficulty would of course be excellent in conjunction with my proposed solution/question.

Comment: So a $G$-module is just a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ modules, so you will still have Frobenius reciprocity, just over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of over $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Are you aware of the correspondence between $G$-actions over $\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathbb{K}[G]$-modules? In your $V_\lambda$ example, the correspondence would *define* $(g_1 + g_2) \cdot x$ as $g_1 \cdot x + g_2 \cdot x$.

Comment: Oh I see! I had sort of seen this mentioned around, but never read anything about it in detail, especially not from say a categorical point of view as most people mention it. It wasn't clear to me that I could just define the $\mathbb{K}[G]$-action to be extended by linearity... I see now that it's unambiguous to do that and I suppose resolves everything! Thanks

Comment: For Frobenius reciprocity over $\Bbb Z$, see also [Shapiro's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%27s_lemma)

Comment: @TrevorGunn would you like to write your comment as an answer? I'd accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural correspondence between $G$-actions over $\mathbb K$  and $\mathbb K[G]$-modules.

If we have a $\mathbb K[G]$-module $V$ then we have a map $f :\mathbb K[G] \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ where $f(x)(v) = x \cdot v$. Given such a map, we can restrict just to the subset $G$ and we obtain a map $\hat f : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(V)$. For an element $g$ of $G$, $f(g)$ of course has to be invertible because $f(g^{-1}) \circ f(g) = \operatorname{id}$.

Conversely, given a map $\hat f : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(V)$, we can extend $\hat f$ linearly to get a map $f :\mathbb K[G] \to \operatorname{End}(V)$. This means that

$$ f(a_1g_1 + \dots + a_r g_r) = a_1 \hat f(g_1) + \dots + a_r \hat f(g_r). $$

In fact, $\mathbb K[G]$ is exactly the $\mathbb K$-algebra you get when you want to extend group homomorphisms $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(V)$ to algebra homomorphisms $\mathbb K[G] \to \operatorname{End}(V)$.